# How many different kinds of insulation film are wrapped around the Apollo Lunar Module?

Tags: apollo-program, lunar-landing, thermal, insulation

In the image shown in the question [Why is the Apollo LM landing gear covered with so much thermal isolation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37871/12102) (also shown below) it appears that the color of the film around the bottoms of the lander's legs is close to "gold color" (though not necessarily related to the metal of the same name) whereas the film on most of the body looks to be a darker red color.

There is also a shiny "metallic" color film and a charcoal gray film as well.

I know there are materials like metallized Kapton and Mylar but I don't know what is used in this case and if there are different thicknesses of the film involved.

1. How many different kinds of insulation film are wrapped around the Apollo Lunar Module?
2. Are the different colorations I'm seeing real? If so, why? Different films or just optics?

[image: Apollo lunar module Image AS11-40-5915.jpg]

Image AS11-40-5915.jpg from [Apollo 11 Lunar Surface Journal](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/images11.html), from [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37871/12102).

Comment: Some more images of these films: https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/AS11-40-5922.jpg https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/AS11-40-5919.jpg https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/AS11-40-5865.jpg https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/AS11-40-5902.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial answer about the medium gray foils.[image]

> The  thermal blanket consists of  multiple-layered (at least 25 
>   layers) of aluminized sheet (mylar or  H-film). Each  layer is only
>   0.00015 inch thick and  is coated on one side with a microinch thickness of aluminum. To make an  even more effective  insulation,
>   the  polymide sheets are hand crinkled before blanket fabrication.
>   This crinkling provides a  path for  venting, and minimizes contact
>   conductance between the layers. Structures with a  high thermal
>   conductivity, such as  antenna supports and  landing gear members,
>   that pass through the  thermal blanket also  have thermal protection.
>   Individual blanket layers are overlapped and  sealed with a 
>   continuous strip of H-film tape.
>
> Mylar sheets are  used predominantly in  those areas where
>   temperatures do  not exceed  300° F.  In  areas where higher
>   temperatures are  sustained, additional  layers of H-film are  added
>   to  the  mylar sheets. H-film can withstand temperatures up  to  1000°
>   F,  but, because it  is  a  heavier material, it  is  used only where
>   absolutely necessary. Certain areas of  the ascent stage are subjected
>   to  temperatures as high as  1800° F  due  to  CSM and LM  RCS plume
>   impingement. These  areas are  thermally controlled by  a sandwich
>   material of thin  nickel foil  (0.0005 inch) interleaved with lnconel 
>   wire mesh and lnconel  sheet.

Block quotes and image from:
APOLLO NEWS REFERENCE LUNAR MODULE QUICK REFERENCE DATA

Comment: Does anybody understand the difference between aluminized polyimide (H-film) and aluminized polyimide (Mylar)? Two different manufacturers of polyimide foils?

Comment: wow, that's complicated stuff!

Comment: @uwe As far as I can tell that's a mistake/oversimplification. H-film is now called Kapton and is a polyimide, however Mylar isn't (strictly speaking). Interestingly both are made by dupont (Mylar and Kapton, its possible h-film was another companies trade-name). Roughly: Mylar is strong reflective and tough. Kapton has (as pointed out) very good resistance to high temperatures. I also is very good at dealing with low temperatures too.

Comment: This is not the first time where I have seen NASA Apollo press kits mistakenly call Mylar and Kapton the same thing; they are not.  (Specific example: the CM thermal protective system.)  If you read the Apollo Experience Reports or the Operations Handbooks (which are documents for a technical audience), the difference is correctly distinguished.